# Not display HTML element if array count is 2nd last laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have made a dynamic select element in **Laravel 5.7**, this is my code:

```
<select>
    @foreach($sbj_topics as $sbj_topic)
        <option value="{{ $sbj_topic->id }}">{{ $sbj_topic->sbj_topic_name }}</option>
        <optgroup label="________________"></optgroup>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

What I need not display `________________`  after the last item.
I tried **end()**, **key()** methods but all in vain, can anyone let me know how to do this?

**Current Result:**

```
option1
_______
option2
_______
option3
_______
```

**I need:**

```
option1
_______
option2
_______
option3
```

Comment: move `@endforeach` one line UP

Comment: bro now it's only showing at the last

Comment: I have edited the question now you can easily understand what I want.

Comment: `@if( ! $loop->last)  // not last  @endif `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the $loop variable
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#the-loop-variable

```
<select>
@foreach($sbj_topics as $sbj_topic)
    <option value="{{ $sbj_topic->id }}">{{ $sbj_topic->sbj_topic_name }}</option>
@if (!$loop->last)
   <optgroup label="________________"></optgroup>
@endif   
@endforeach
```

Comment: or instead of `@if` you can use `@unless` which is more readable then using `!` in the condition.